# jQuery - get closest element in different div levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am clicking the list button with `class="btn btn-primary modal-save"`.

When I click that button, I want it to grab the `textarea` element of `div class="modal-body"`.

For some reason my `closest()` method isn't functioning the way I want it to be, and returns undefined

Why, and how to fix?

```js
$('.modal-save').on('click', function() {

  var text = $(this).closest(".modal-footer")[0];
  console.log(text) // this code works

  var text = $(this).closest(".modal-body textarea")[0];
  console.log(text) // this gives me undefined. Why??


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">...</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder='comment...'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-save" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Closet searches an element's ancestors (think parent and grandparents - it doesn't look at cousins).  Your best approach is probably to go up some amount and then look downward (with .find() probably).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`closest` returns the nearest *ancestor* matching the selector. If it's not a direct ancestor, it won't work. Try selecting the `.modal-content` first (which is the nearest common ancestor to both), and *then* trying to find the `textarea`:

```js
$('.modal-save').on('click', function() {
  var text = $(this).closest(".modal-content").find("textarea");
  console.log(text.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">...</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder='comment...'>foo</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-save" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the `textarea` this way.

```
$(this).closest(".modal-footer").prev(".modal-body").find("textarea")[0]
//          ^^go for parent       ^^go for sibling    ^^Its child
```

**Example:**

```js
$('.modal-save').on('click', function() {
  var text = $(this).closest(".modal-footer")[0];
  console.log(text) // this code works

  var text = $(this).closest(".modal-footer").prev(".modal-body").find("textarea")[0];
  console.log(text)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">...</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder='comment...'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-save" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution.

I've split everything up into steps so you would understand clearer.

Using [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) you access the DOM element that is top-most relative to your element.

Using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) you get the descendants of each element in the current set.

---

```js
$('.modal-save').on('click', function() {

  let footer   = $(this).parent();
  let content  = footer.parent();
  let textarea = content.find('.modal-body textarea');
  let text     = textarea.val();
  
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">...</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder='comment...'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-save" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have targeted the text-area for faster execution.

```
alert($('.modal-body textarea').val());
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/401754/)

Comment: This won't work if there's more than one `.modal-body`.